# MySQL Query Performance - Subquery Vs Join

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, left-join

I'm not a SQL expert, so am trying to understand why two queries have substantially different execution times.

common_stats is a large table (3 million rows). I'm just trying to understand why the huge difference in performance.

The below query takes ~15 seconds:

```
select distinct cs.basesalary_id
from common_stats AS cs
LEFT JOIN basesalary AS b ON b.id = cs.basesalary_id
WHERE (b.employee_id= 100 AND cs.amount > 0 AND cs.pay_id is null );
```

This query takes ~.1 seconds:

```
select distinct basesalary_id from (
    select cs.basesalary_id, cs.pay_id
    from common_stats AS cs
    LEFT JOIN basesalary AS b ON b.id = cs.basesalary_id
    WHERE (b.employee_id= 100 AND cs.amount > 0)
) as temp
where pay_id is null;
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `explain` in front of the query and comparing the execution plans?

Comment: @e4c5 But this example is a subquery significantly outperforming a join.

Comment: Bit of a duplicate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query

Comment: @Phylogenesis oh sorry I misread that one!

Comment: Always use `EXPLAIN` (and do post its output here). Always ensure you're not pulling from query cache by issuing `RESET QUERY CACHE;` if you have two queries that operate on the same data. Another very, very important thing to bear in mind - you can optimize SQL to infinity and beyond but hardware plays a hugely important role. It's important to know which engine you're using and whether it uses your hardware optimally.

Comment: Could you provide sqlfiddle please?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule:

- If the subquery 'shrinks' the number of rows (say, via `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT`), the subquery approach is better.
- `JOIN` often creates more rows than the original tables.  `DISTINCT` is sometime used to deflate that row count.
- If the outer query has a `GROUP BY`, `JOIN` *may* create more rows than you realize and "inflate" any aggregates (`SUM`, `COUNT`, etc), thereby voting for subquery instead.
- More than one subquery would lead to poor optimization.  (Thereby voting for `JOIN`.)

All of those assume optimal indexes.

Your first query would probably benefit from

```
INDEX(pay_id, amount, basesalary_id) -- both "covering" and optimal for `WHERE`
```

Check out `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both queries.  Probably the faster one starts with `basesalary` and there is `INDEX(employee_id)` and that is very selective.

I may have more comments after seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: When using a subquery, the explain shows the following sequence:
1 - PRIMARY - NO KEYS - 667154 rows - Extra: "Using where"
2 - DERIVED - NO KEYS - 667154 rows - Extra: none
3 - DERIVED - PRIMARY KEY - 1 row - Extra: none
When using a join, explain shows this sequence:
1 - SIMPLE - NO KEYS - 667171 rows - Extra: none
2 - SIMPLE - PRIMARY KEY - 1 row - Extra: using where

Comment: I'm sorry; that is too hard to read; please edit your Question to add it.